# How to do this asymptotic task?

Tags: asymptotics

Let a(n) be the amount of natural numbers, which are smaller than n, and their prime divisors are only 2 and 3.

For example: 6 is good, because it only has 2 and 3 has prime divisors, but 10 is not good because it has 5 as a prime divisor. 12 is good too, because it's prime divisors are only 2 and 3, since 4 and 6  are not primes.

How much is a(n) asymptotic if n goes until infinity?

Comment: These are the 3-smooth numbers: http://oeis.org/A003586

Comment: I see that they tell an asymptotic formula, but how exactly is it proven? :)

Comment: Perhaps you could send a message to Benoit Cloitre, who posted that on OEIS, to ask.